# Delete keys whose name contains certain characters from an object (Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My coding skills are VERY rudimentary, so this might be a very dumb question.

Anyway here goes...

I have a simple coffeescript program that runs every few minutes and saves an array of extra data into the `storage` object with a timestamp appended onto the key name:

```
extra_data = (big long array of thousands of numbers)
newKey = "extra_data_#{@data.at}"
@storage[newKey] = extra_data
```

So now I have a bunch of arrays saved in the `storage` object that look like this:

```
storage.extra_data_1820348106
storage.extra_data_1239861234
storage.extra_data_1908234710
```

I need to delete all of these keys but leave the rest of the `storage` object alone. What is the simplest way to delete only the keys which contain `extra_data` (in the name of the key) in CoffeeScript?

I attempted:

```
delete @storage[/extra_data/g]
```

and this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **for ... in** loop to get all keys and value:

```
for own key of @storage
    if (/extra_data/g.test(key))
        delete @storage[key]
```

Or with ES6+

```
Object.keys(@storage).forEach((key)
    -> if (/extra_data/g.test(key))
        delete @storage[key]
        return
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through each key:

```
for own k of storage
    if (k.includes("extra_data")) delete @storage[k]
```